# Does coalesce(numPartitions) in spark undergo shuffling or not?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple question in spark transformation function.

coalesce(numPartitions) -   Decrease the number of partitions in the RDD to numPartitions. Useful for running operations more efficiently after filtering down a large dataset.

```
val dataRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/inputfiles/records.txt")
val filterRDD = dataRDD.filter(record => record.split(0) == "USA")
val resizeRDD = filterRDD.coalesce(50)
val result    = resizeRDD.collect
```

My question is

1. Is it true that coalesce(numPartitions)  will remove the empty partitions  from filterRDD?
2. Does coalesce(numPartitions)  undergo shuffling or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `coalesce` transformation is used to reduce the number of partitions. `coalesce` should be used if the number of output partitions is less than the input. It can trigger RDD shuffling depending on the shuffle flag which is disabled by default (i.e. false).

If number of partitions is larger than current number of partitions and you are using `coalesce` method without shuffle=true flag then number of partitions remains unchanged.`coalesce` doesn't guarantee that the empty partitions will be removed. For example if you have 20 empty partitions and 10 partitions with data, then there will still be empty partitions after you call `rdd.coalesce(25)`. If you use `coalesce` with shuffle set to true then this will be equivalent to `repartition` method and data will be evenly distributed across the partitions.

Comment: Additionally, one thing that must be kept in mind while using `coalesce` is that it could lead to **reduced parallelism**. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891929) for details