# Coalesce reducing JDBC read parallelism

Tags: apache-spark

I leverage `Spark`'s `JDBC` capabilities as follows:

- Read `MySQL` tables into `DataFrame`
- *Transform* them
- *Coalesce* them
- Write them to `HDFS`

Throughout the lifespan of `DataFrame`, **no `action`s are performed** on it. It used to work as expected but lately I've been experiencing problems. Thanks to `Spark`'s *lazy evaluation*, the `coalesce` is resulting in reduced *parallelism* of read operation.

---

So if I read `DataFrame` using `DataFrameReader.jdbc(..numPartitions..)` with `numPartitions=42`, and then `coalesce` it to 6 `partition`s before writing, then it reads the `DataFrame` with a *concurrency* of only 6 (fire only 6 queries to `MySQL`). I'd like to repeat that earlier it used read with *parallelism* of 42 and perform `coalesce` afterwards.

I've recently migrated to `Spark 2.3.0` on `EMR 5.13`, could this be related to that? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Thanks to Spark's lazy evaluation, the coalesce is resulting in reduced parallelism of read operation.

It has nothing to do with laziness. `coalesce` intentionally doesn't create [analysis barrier](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@coalesce(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):

> However, if you're doing a drastic coalesce, e.g. to numPartitions = 1, this may result in your computation taking place on fewer nodes than you like (e.g. one node in the case of numPartitions = 1). To avoid this, you can call repartition. This will add a shuffle step, but means the current upstream partitions will be executed in parallel (per whatever the current partitioning is).

So just follow the documentation and use `repartition` instead of `coalesce`.

Comment: If I understood the given statement correctly, then I have to use `repartition` instead of `coalesce` (with same `numPartitions`) to overcome the issue I'm facing. And though that would result in a **full shuffle**, it would still get rid of this so called *reduced parallelism*. Is that correct?

Comment: It is not _so called_ - it is literally a an upper bound for concurrency.

Comment: That was indeed the case. That means **lower concurrency** is the price you pay when you try to *avoid* a *full shuffle* by using `coalesce` instead of `repartition`