# Spark Performance Issue vs Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am working on a pipeline that will run daily. It includes joining 2 tables say x & y ( approx. 18 MB and 1.5 GB sizes respectively) and loading the output of the join to final table.

Following are the facts about the environment,

For table x:

- Data size: 18 MB
- Number of files in a partition : ~191
- file type: parquet

For table y:

- Data size: 1.5 GB
- Number of files in a partition : ~3200
- file type: parquet

Now the problem is:

### Hive and Spark are giving same performance (time taken is same)

I tried different combination of resources for spark job.

e.g.:

- executors:50 memory:20GB cores:5
- executors:70 memory:20GB cores:5
- executors:1 memory:20GB cores:5

All three combinations are giving same performance. I am not sure what I am missing here.

I also tried broadcasting the small table 'x' so as to avoid shuffle while joining but not much improvement in performance.

One key observations is:

70% of the execution time is consumed for reading the big table 'y' and I guess this is due to more number of files per partition.

I am  not sure how hive is giving the same performance.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: 3200 splits for 1.5GB is a bit much, I think. Might be helpful if you merge the splits or repartition.

Comment: True! I understand that but the problem is we have only one copy of data and we are skeptical to do anything to it. Also, re partitioning it would again induce a shuffle right? I already tried that.

Comment: I once faced the same issue - it was primarily because of the number of splits. Some helpful properties `hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true`, `hive.auto.convert.join = true`,  `hive.merge.sparkfiles=true`.

Comment: I also feel its due to the number of splits and we want to use spark. Will hive config help here?

Comment: Which execution engine are you using with Hive?

Comment: We are still using Map Reduce.

Comment: I assumed you were using Hive on Spark.

Answer (score 0):

**I assume you are comparing Hive on MR vs Spark. Please let me know if it is not the case.Because Hive(on tez or spark) vs Spark Sql will not differ 
vastly in terms of performance.**

I think the main issue is that there are too many small files.
A lot of CPU and time is consumed in the I/O itself, hence you can't experience the processing power of Spark.

My advice is to coalesce the spark dataframes immedietely after reading the parquet files. Please coalesce the 'x' dataframe into single partition and 'y' 
dataframe into 6-7 partitions.

After doing the above, please perform the join(broadcastHashJoin).

Comment: I am not sure please is necessary when offering advice.

Comment: I think it is the number of files too but again if we do a coalesce there will be a shuffle induced right? It would increase the time of execution furthermore if I am not wrong.

Comment: Coalesce doesn't cause the shuffle, repartition does.

Comment: As per my understanding, coalesce and re-partition both induce shuffle but coalesce is faster as it does not shuffle the entire data. It transfer the data from other nodes to the selected nodes where as re-partition shuffles the entire data across selected nodes. I will still give it a try and let you know!

Comment: Also, If i coalesce the small table 'x' and broadcast it how it will makes performance better as broadcasting the x will make it available on all worker nodes as a single copy(driver collects all the data and broadcasts it). Why coalesce?

Comment: Coalesce is primarily used to consolidate too many partitions into a few so that resource utilization gets better. It will not, by default, cause the shuffle(Please check other answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034314/does-coalescenumpartitions-in-spark-undergo-shuffling-or-not)